# Colocando codigo html dentro de php

Tags: php

Estou tentando colocar um codigo html dentro de um php e não tá dando certo, como faço para encaixar códigos html dentro de php ?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['buscarNome']) && $_POST['buscarNome'] == 'Buscar') {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    if(empty($nome)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Informe o nome!');javascript:window.location='consulta.php';</script>";
    }else {
        $strcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "estagio") or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro ao conectar no banco de dados!');javascript:window.location='consulta.php';</script>");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE nome LIKE '%''nome''%'";
        $con = mysqli_query($strcon, $sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro ao tentar fazer a consulta');javascript:window.location='consulta.php';</script>");
echo<<<HTML
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>CPF</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Sexo</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
        <td>Cidade</td>
        <td>Telefone</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dado['cpf']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['sexo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['idade']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['cidade']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['telefone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
HTML;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é que esta linha aqui:

```
<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
```

está dentro de um HEREDOC, então ela é tratada como texto, e não como PHP.

A solução sem mexer muito no seu código é algo assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['buscarNome']) && $_POST['buscarNome'] == 'Buscar') {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
}
if(empty($nome)){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Informe o nome!');javascript:window.location='consulta.php';</script>";
}else {
    $strcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "estagio") or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro ao conectar no banco de dados!');javascript:window.location='consulta.php';</script>");
    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string( $strcon, $nome );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE nome LIKE '%".$nome."%'";
    $con = mysqli_query($strcon, $sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro ao tentar fazer a consulta');javascript:window.location='consulta.php';</script>");
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>CPF</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Sexo</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
        <td>Cidade</td>
        <td>Telefone</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>
<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dado['cpf']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['sexo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['idade']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['cidade']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['telefone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
'</table>';
<?php } ?>
```

Note também a adoção desta linha, para evitar SQL Injection:

```
        $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string( $strcon, $nome );
```

Para evitar confusão, compensa repensar no código para evitar muito abre e fecha de `<?php ?>` misturado com `echo`.

Ao contrário do que se prega, não tem problema misturar PHP com HTML (afinal, o PHP foi feito pra isso), porém cada caso é um caso, e no seu código está ficando um pouco confuso, então convém conhecer maneiras diferentes de se organizar.